# Trying to do Dynamic Equity Split calculations in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

new to using javascript in Google Sheets. I am trying to create a sheet that automatically calculates what business partners will receive based upon their dynamic split percentage and the incoming money. The percentage comes from one cell, but each payment made to the partners will be entered in a column. Here's what I have so far:

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
* Also performs dynamic split calculations
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 13;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,-1];
// Where the calculations will be performed for the Partners.
var PARTNERONELOCATION = [0, 1];
var PARTNERTWOLOCATION = [0, 2];
var PARTNERTHREELOCATION = [0, 3];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME1 = 'Sheet1'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var partnerOnePercent = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var partnerOnePaySource = sheet.getRange("M2").getValue();
  var partnerTwoPercent = sheet.getRange("G3").getValue();
  var partnerTwoPaySource = sheet.getRange("M2").getValue();
  var partnerThreePercent = sheet.getRange("G4").getValue();
  var partnerThreePaySource = sheet.getRange("M2").getValue();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME1 ) {
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date and calculations to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      var partnerOneCell = selectedCell.offset(PARTNERONELOCATION[0],PARTNERONELOCATION[1]);
      partnerOneCell.setValue((partnerOnePercent/100)*partnerOnePaySource);
      var partnerTwoCell = selectedCell.offset(PARTNERTWOLOCATION[0],PARTNERTWOLOCATION[1]);
      partnerTwoCell.setValue((partnerTwoPercent/100)*partnerTwoPaySource);
      var partnerThreeCell = selectedCell.offset(PARTNERTHREELOCATION[0],PARTNERTHREELOCATION[1]);
      partnerThreeCell.setValue((partnerThreePercent/100)*partnerThreePaySource);
      }
  }
}
```

The thing I would like it to do is when I enter a payment into the column (column 13), Is for the payment to be split into the partner location cells (var partnerOneCell, var partnerTwoCell, var partnerThreeCell) that are offset from the cell that the payment amount is typed in, and I only want it to be calculated by the percentages as they are at the moment the payment amount is entered. Any help would be appreciated.

Right now it is only calculating based upon cell M2 (row 2, column 13). I want it to be able to calculate based upon the amount I enter in any cell within that column, and only the cell I am currently updating. I think that this has something to do with getActiveRange or something, but I'm not familiar enough with these methods.

**Edit:** Upon testing, it also seems that row 3 column 14 is reflecting a calculation of partnerOnePaySource*partnerOnePercent with PaySource coming from row 3 column 13 (M3), though I'm not sure why.

Comment: FYI, I fixed the exception error and the fact that PARTNERTWOLOCATION and PARTNERTHREELOCATION didn't seem to be operating their equation. I just need to do something with the column. The split formula is only operating off of Cell M2 right now, and I need it to be able to operate from other cells in that same column as well (M3, M4, M5 etc...)

Comment: Hi! Could you please share a Spreadsheet with some dummy data? If you fixed part of your question, please edit it in order to make it more readable and more focus in your actual issue (Make an operation when there is a change in M3, M4, M5 etc..., right?)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It has been updated to reflect the current state of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright everyone, after reading over my code, I realized how I could use the getActiveCell method within the PaySource variables.

```
var partnerOnePercent = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var partnerOnePaySource = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
  var partnerTwoPercent = sheet.getRange("G3").getValue();
  var partnerTwoPaySource = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
  var partnerThreePercent = sheet.getRange("G4").getValue();
  var partnerThreePaySource = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
```

With this I was able to fix my problem and it now works.